# yum install php-idn not working on centos 6.6

Tags: php, centos6, php-extension

trying to install `php-idn` as I was getting `Fatal error: Call to undefined function Pdp\idn_to_ascii(` 
while installing `php-idn`, I got following error.
I am running on `CentOs 6.6` and PHP 5.5

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Setting up Install Process
Repository pgdg93 is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository pgdg93-source is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.usc.edu
 * epel: mirrors.kernel.org
 * extras: mirror.tocici.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: mirror.keystealth.org
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-idn.x86_64 0:1.2c-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-idn-1.2c-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-idn-1.2c-1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-idn-1.2c-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.5.20-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
Error: Package: php-idn-1.2c-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.5.20-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Also tried installing it with

```
rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/php-idn-1.2c-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall epel and do a `yum clean all` then reinstall the latest epel and your package.

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

There may also be conflicts with epel and rpmforge. They CAN both be used together with yum priorities or protectbase. See: http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/ProtectBase